# How to apply where clause on ManytoOne Join field on hibernate search?

Tags: hibernate, lucene, hibernate-search

I have a *Product* table and it has fields *Name*, *SKU*, *Description* and *Product category* (a many to one relationship with product category table). I indexed *Product* using Hibernate Search and have written the following code to perform a search:

```
FullTextEntityManager fullTextEntityManager = org.hibernate.search.jpa.Search
            .getFullTextEntityManager(getEntityManager());
QueryBuilder qb = fullTextEntityManager.getSearchFactory()
            .buildQueryBuilder().forEntity(Product.class).get();

    org.apache.lucene.search.Query query = qb.keyword().fuzzy()
            .onFields("name", "sku", "uniqueid", "description")
            .matching(value).createQuery();
    javax.persistence.Query persistenceQuery = fullTextEntityManager
            .createFullTextQuery(query, Product.class);
```

Now I would like to add a where condition on the product category. For example, I would like to search only the products where productCategory.Id=101.

Could anyone suggest me how I can do this?

Thanks & Regards
Vijay

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should work (you need to combine queries using *bool*):

```
Query fuzzyQuery = qb.keyword()
    .fuzzy()
    .onFields("name", "sku", "uniqueid", "description")
    .matching(value)
    .createQuery();

Query categoryQuery = qb.keyword()
    .onField("productCategory.Id")
    .matching("101")
    .createQuery();

Query luceneQuery = qb
    .bool()
      .should( fuzzyQuery )
      .must( categoryQuery )
    .createQuery();
```

Something like this. It depends really how exactly you configured your entities. Really you should talk about entities and not tables when you make your example and you should post the code for your annotated entities.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. In my Product domain class i have annotated Cateogry as -ManyToOne
 -JoinColumn(name="PL_PRODUCTCATEGORY_ID")
    -IndexedEmbedded
 private ProductCategory Productcategory;' and in ProductCategory domain class i have annotated products as  -OneToMany(mappedBy="Productcategory")
 -ContainedIn
 private List<Product> Products;

Comment: can you suggest me the best way to find out based on categories?

Comment: All the annotations you mentioned are JPA (ORM) mapping annotations. To index and search associations via Hibernate Search you need to make use if @IndexedEmbedded. Have a look at the documentation for examples.